# jQuery 'on' event is different while using Ember JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

While binding function to a html element using jQuery '***on***', why callback function **func** having **on** attribute in Ember JS which is not available in JQuery.

**jQuery Application:**

```
$('body').append("<div id='div1'></div>")
var func = function(){alert("Ember")};
var bind = $("#div1").on("click",func);
"on" in func  // returns false
```

**Ember Application**

```
$('body').append("<div id='div1'></div>")
var func = function(){alert("Ember")};
var bind = $("#div1").on("click",func);
"on" in func // returns true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please set **false** in **EXTEND_PROTOTYPES**  in environment.js file. Please refer the below code snippets.You can achive this your output

```
var ENV = {
     ------
EmberENV: {
  FEATURES: {
    // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
    // e.g. 'with-controller': true
  },
  EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: false
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not about jQuery's `on` function.

Ember has prototype extension feature. Ember extends function's, array's and string's prototype. The `on` is about function prototype extension. You can see the code from [github repo](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/d0de6ae3a77ab5a5156e62d3be7543302caf8c0f/packages/ember-runtime/lib/ext/function.js#L194).

You can also have a look at [disabling prototype extensions](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/#toc_functions) from the guide.